# Need info about how to associate my applications file extensions with the application using InstallShield 2010

Tags: windows, registry, installshield, file-extension

I am using InstallShield 2010 to create an installer for my application but I am having trouble finding any info about how to associate the file extensions my applications uses with the application.  Can anyone link me to some docs or give me a quick run down on how to do this?  My application is a java application and I am trying to create the installer for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write to the registry to create file associations, specifically in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT section. Here are couple of links which may you:
http://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-88.html
http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=106732
http://phi.lho.free.fr/windows_tips/FileAssociations.en.html